# bootstrap float-right not moving element to right

Tags: bootstrap-4, css-float

I'm trying to learn bootstrap.  The navbar has the entire width of the browser.  The form is in the navbar.  Why doesn't float-right move the search box to the right?

I notice that if I replace the float with ml-auto it works but was wondering why the float class doesn't work

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark ">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            <form class="form-inline float-sm-right">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </nav>
    </body>

</html>.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't mix floats and flexbox. (Floats are outdated and a pain anyway.) The navbar has flex styles on it, so [use that to align its content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/#align-self). The `align-self-end` class is your huckleberry (or `align-self-sm-end` to implement your breakpoint). Note that we also use `flex-fill` on the unordered list element to make it use the extra space.

Make the demo full page to see it in action.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark ">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-fill">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <form class="form-inline align-self-end">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </nav>
    </body>

</html>.
```